# Route VS NAT: when and why user either of them

Tags: networking

I thought that I had understood the difference between NAT and Route by now, but I realized that it isn't yet all clear to me, and I still need to delve into this networking subject.

I know that NAT allows private IPs to be routed across a public network. But I can have NAT in my own private network too (in fact, I am under double NAT). Furthermore, my Mikrotik can ROUTE between two subnets by removing, for example, an interface from the bridge and setup a different subnet on it, with a different dhcp server as well.

So, if you were to make me to understand what is the difference between NAT and Route, what would you tell me? When and why I need NAT or ROUTE?

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a private / home network; A simple answer, hopefully sorting out the first bit of it...

NAT - Network Address Translation
Is usually what a FIREWALL does. IP-numbers from local LAN get translated to the IP of the firewall; which is the only IP that will be visible on the external side, on the WAN. I'd expect a router to be delivered with a firewall enabled. No need to tweak anything.

ROUTE - Telling IP-packets where to go next.
Today this is most often something that you do not need to bother with; unless you have very specific and special needs or wishes.

Normally: Set your router to act as DHCP-server (=Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol, using e.g. 192.168.0.1 to .254 as address range, and 255.255.255.0 as netmask) and set all your computers /printers/TV /whatever to use DHCP - and that is it.
The router will figure out all the rest by itself.
If you have a second router, or switch or something similar; you may set IT to get it's configuration from the first router; then connecting devices to either router will work nicely.

If you install either Linux or Windows - they are all set to DHCP *by default*.

Comment: I think I still need to delve a bit into it. Thanks anyway

Comment: FWIW; I have been using "internet" since very early days, generally / personally I haven't needed more advanced settings than described above in years. And I do need set up networking at work, now and then. Now: Quickly write down details in your question; what it is you're after. If you cannot specify it, the Q will probably end up closed.

Comment: I thought that I finally had understood what NAT was about and used for (IPv4 exhaustion problem, masquerade etc) but I ran across this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_UUnlVC2Ss
(see from minute 13:00 in particular)
 which confused me. Why does he need to use NAT? Thanks

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing) - also; keep questions single subject, note that comments are not a discussion forum.

Comment: @jeysmith NAT = firewall filtering and masquerading | Route = packet routing. An overly simplistic view is NAT is what the WAN interface on a router does, routing is what occurs afterwards on the LAN interfaces. This is also what separates a router from a switch - switches route packets, but cannot do NAT, and this is also why a router is always required between a modem and downstream devices.